# Can Json.NET deserialize "dynamic" properties?

Tags: c#, json

my C# service is receiving objects from an external service with a "fuzzy" format that looks like:

```
{
  "member": {
      "<dynamicProperty>": {
          "value":"some_string",
          "score": 10
      }
}
```

This property "" can change for every object, I don't have a defined and restricted list for its possible values and of course I can't change this format.

Does anybody know if Json.NET or some other Json .NET serializer, could help me and allow me to define classes like `Member` and `DynamicProperty` below that I could use for an easy deserialization?

```
class Member
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName= "??")] // what should I put here?
    public DynamicProperty { get; set; }
}

class DynamicProperty
{
    public string value;
    public int score;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Would a dictionary work? Does `member` have other properties?

Comment: member has other properties but simple ones (by simple I mean they don't change) so yeah actually a dictionary should do the job! I hadn't thought of it but it's so easy!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
class Member
{
     public Dictionary<string, object> { get; set; }
}
```

Or, you can use the [`JsonExtensionData`](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/10/14/json-net-5-0-release-7-immutable-collections) Attribute:

```
class Member
{
     [JsonExtensionData]
     public Dictionary<string, JToken> { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm even going to use Dictionary<string, FuzzyProperty>  (I should just find a better name)

Comment: But FuzzyProperty contains two members. Which means one will always contain an empty value.

Comment: really? he won't be able to deserialize the dictionary value as an instance of the class DyanmicProperty (I've renamed FuzzyProperty into DynamicProperty)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. Put the data in like this:

```
var data1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONX>(readJSON);
```

This is the class from Yuval's example above:

```
class recordxy
{
[JsonExtensionData]
public Dictionary<string, object> DataItems { get; set; }
}
```

Pull the key's and value's out like this:

```
foreach (var item in data1...DataItems)
{
Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```